# Save to engine camunda( version 7.9) variable type 'Date'

Tags: javascript, camunda

I want to save variable 'beauftragungsdatum' type 'Date' to engine :

```
inject(['$http', 'Uri', function($http, Uri) {
camForm.on('store', function(evt) {
evt.retrieveVariables()

var varManager = evt.variableManager;
var vars = varManager.variables;
var dataVar = $scope.beauftragungsdatum;
varManager.variableValue('beauftragungsdatum', dataVar);
var variableData = {};
      for(var v in vars) {
        if(varManager.isDirty(v)) {
          var val = vars[v].value;
          if(varManager.isJsonVariable(v)) {
            val = JSON.stringify(val);
          }
          variableData[v] = {
            value: val,
            type: vars[v].type,
            valueInfo: vars[v].valueInfo
          };
        }
      }

      var data = { modifications: variableData };
      var config = {
        headers : {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      };
      $http.post(Uri.appUri('engine://engine/:engine/task/' + camForm.taskId + '/variables'), data, config);
      evt.storePrevented = true;
    });
  }]);
```

At the save moment I have a problem : variable 'beauftragungsdatum' is not type of date. I found out that var have wrong format. I fixed it and paste some decision:

```
 inject(['$http', 'Uri', function($http, Uri) {
    camForm.on('store', function(evt) {
    evt.retrieveVariables()

    var varManager = evt.variableManager;
    var vars = varManager.variables;
    var now=moment(dataVar).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZZ");
    console.log(now);
    console.log(typeof now);
    var d=varManager.variableValue('beauftragungsdatum');
    console.log(d);
    console.log(typeof d);

  varManager.variableValue('beauftragungsdatum')=now;
    var variableData = {};
          for(var v in vars) {
            if(varManager.isDirty(v)) {
              var val = vars[v].value;
              if(varManager.isJsonVariable(v)) {
                val = JSON.stringify(val);
              }
              variableData[v] = {
                value: val,
                type: vars[v].type,
                valueInfo: vars[v].valueInfo
              };
            }
          }

          var data = { modifications: variableData };
          var config = {
            headers : {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
          };
          $http.post(Uri.appUri('engine://engine/:engine/task/' + camForm.taskId + '/variables'), data, config);
          evt.storePrevented = true;
        });
      }]);
```

As a result i have a problem attach file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhYd1.png)
I need help in this question , may be know how save var 'Date' in Camunda 7.9.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line, the value you are placing inside `now` is a string:

```
var now=moment(dataVar).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZZ");
```

The `format` method returns a string in the format you specify.

if you want to get a Date object, use `moment(dataVar).toDate()`.

Comment: Hi, Shai. You mean that i must write something like this:
var now=moment(dataVar).toDate();
and after that:
varManager.variableValue('beauftragungsdatum', now) ;
As a result I have a  problem :
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2018-08-08T03:00:00.000Z': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2018-08-08T03:00:00.000Z': Unparseable date: "2018-08-08T03:00:00.000Z")
 at [Source: "2018-08-08T03:00:00.000Z"; line: 1, column: 1]

Comment: I think here : varManager.variableValue('beauftragungsdatum', now) ;

Comment: You need to make sure. Try placing a breakpoint and see where and when the error occurs.

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the first line and then run the lines one by one until one of them throws the exception.